# given a list of names how to insert delete display search and exit? javaprogram

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

Given a list of employees create a simple program that allows the user to insert, delete, display and search an employee.

The program should display 10 employees. Also, a list of menu should be displayed. The menu names are Insert, Delete Display and Search

Comment: where did you get stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

How I'd go about doing it is using an ArrayList. Create a new Object called "Employee," the constructor should include the Employee's name (in the form of a string). Initialize an empty ArrayList of Employees and add each Employee to the ArrayList. Searching for each employee is a matter of using a Scanner object (`import java.util.Scanner`) and a `for` loop to loop through the ArrayList to find the name of each employee.